# Adding UISearchBar in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, iphone-sdk-4.3

I Added UISearchBar in UINavigationBar and its showing also but the delegate methods are not working. My code is as follows:

**MainViewController.h**

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>  {

}

@property(nonatomic, readonly) UISearchBar *_searchBar;
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UISearchBarDelegate> delegate;
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad  {
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    _searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    
initWithCustomView:_searchBar];
    _searchBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText  {
    NSLog(@"textDidChange is firing with %@",searchText);
}
```

Its not showing even the typed text only! Please give me suggestions.Thank You!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here. The only suspicious thing is the 'delegate' property in MainViewController. Could there be anywhere where _searchBar.delegate could be set to self.delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the search bar in interface builder to the code.  It has to be an IBOutlet.

The code will look like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

and you don't need to declare

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UISearchBarDelegate> delegate;
```